# How to update a field on child record when parent is updated and parent record when child record is updated if both are same object

Tags: apex, trigger

Here is the requirement:

On Agreement object I have Termination date and Status category field. One agreement can have multiple childs. If Status category of parent agreement is Terminated then On child agreement Termination date field should be same as Termination Date on Parent agreement. 
Same like If Status category of child agreement is Terminated then On parent agreement Termination date field should be same as Termination Date on child agreement.
 I have created a trigger but it is not working for both update. If both triggers are active, it is working for single update. when parent-child update trigger is inactive that time Child-parent update is working as same like when child-Parent update trigger is inactive that time parent-child update is working. 
   I am not whether am missed anything or it is working as design. Can we achieve this?

Trigger for updating parent agreement when child is updated:

```
trigger UpdateTerminationDateTrigger on Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c (after insert,after update) {

    if(UpdateTerminationDate.isFirstTime){
        UpdateTerminationDate.isFirstTime = false;

        List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> agreement = [select id,Name,Apttus__Parent_Agreement__r.Apttus__Status_Category__c,CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c,Apttus__Parent_Agreement__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c,Apttus__Parent_Agreement__c,Apttus__Status_Category__c,Apttus__Status__c,Apttus__Parent_Agreement__r.Apttus__Status__c 
                                                     from Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c 
                                                     where id in :Trigger.New 
                                                     AND Apttus__Status_Category__c = 'Terminated'
                                                     AND Apttus__Parent_Agreement__c != null];  

        Map<Id, Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> parentAgreements = new Map<Id, Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c>();

        for(Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c ag : agreement){
            if(!parentAgreements.containsKey(ag.Apttus__Parent_Agreement__c)) {

                Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c p = new Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c();
                p.Id = ag.Apttus__Parent_Agreement__c;
                p.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c = ag.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c;

                parentAgreements.put(ag.Apttus__Parent_Agreement__c, p);
            }

        }

      update parentAgreements.values();    
    }
}
```

Trigger for updating child when parent is updated

```
trigger TerminationDateOnParent on Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c (after insert,after update) {

    if(TerminationDate.isFirstTime){
        TerminationDate.isFirstTime = false;

     List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> agreement = [select id,Name,Apttus__Parent_Agreement__r.Apttus__Status_Category__c,CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c,Apttus__Parent_Agreement__r.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c,Apttus__Parent_Agreement__c,Apttus__Status_Category__c,Apttus__Status__c,Apttus__Parent_Agreement__r.Apttus__Status__c 
                                                     from Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c 
                                                     where Apttus__Parent_Agreement__r.id in :Trigger.New 

                                                     ];  


      //  Map<Id, Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> parentAgreements = new Map<Id, Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c>();
List<Id> Ids=new List<Id>();

        for(Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c ag : agreement){
            Ids.add(ag.Apttus__Parent_Agreement__c);

        }
List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> Paragreement = [select id,Name,Apttus__Status_Category__c,CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c,Apttus__Status__c
                                                     from Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c 
                                                     where id in :Ids
                                                     AND Apttus__Status_Category__c = 'Terminated'
                                                     ];

       List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> agr=new List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c>();

        for(Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c paragr:Paragreement) {
            for(Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c chiagr:agreement){
                chiagr.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c=paragr.CLM_Agreement_Termination_Date__c;
                chiagr.Apttus__Status_Category__c=paragr.Apttus__Status_Category__c;
                agr.add(chiagr);
            }

        }
        update agr;
    } 

}
```

Comment: What is your child object name? I can see the both triggers are written on the same object and there might be an issue of order of execution.

Comment: @Lokesh Kumar Both parent and child object are same

Comment: oh! man. Never write two triggers on same object mostly for the same event. Write your logic in one trigger and do the SOQL to get the child and parent record. And accordingly do the update. The logic which you have written is fine due to an order of execution you are getting this issue.